# Upgraded Ubuntu from 14.04 LTS to 16.04 LTS and Bugzilla stopped working

Tags: bugzilla, ubuntu-16.04

I just upgraded my Ubuntu server from 14.04 LTS to 16.04 LTS. Upgrading the OS to a major new release always makes me nervous. Of course something had to break... bugzilla stopped working. I got the following output from my web browser:

> Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator at webmaster@localhost to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you
>   performed just before this error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Looking at the /var/log/apache2/error.log I saw the following:

> AH01215: /usr/bin/perl: symbol lookup error:
>   lib/i686-linux-gnu-thread-multi-64int/auto/List/Util/Util.so:
>   undefined symbol: Perl_xs_apiversion_bootcheck:
>   /var/www/htmls/bugzilla/index.cgi

I spent hours searching the web for a solution.  **No luck.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried following the docs to make sure I had all the required packages (which I did), in particular I focused on the following section from the installation section of the docs:

> Bugzilla comes with a checksetup.pl script which helps with the
>   installation process. It will need to be run twice. The first time, it
>   generates a config file (called localconfig) for the database access
>   information, and the second time (step 10) it uses the info you put in
>   the config file to set up the database.

```
cd /var/www/html/bugzilla
./checksetup.pl
```

running this command resulted in:

> /usr/bin/perl: symbol lookup error:
>   lib/i686-linux-gnu-thread-multi-64int/auto/List/Util/Util.so:
>   undefined symbol: Perl_xs_apiversion_bootcheck

Same problem, so I searched the web for more ideas -- no help.

I decided to try a clean install by cloning a fresh version of bugzilla from GitHub into a temporary directory and running the ./checksetup.pl command.  It rebuilt everything. So I renamed

```
/var/www/htmls/bugzilla/lib
```

to

```
/var/www/htmls/bugzilla/oldlib
```

and ran the command

```
./checksetup.pl
```

in the /var/www/htmls/bugzilla directory

**PRESTO!!!**

It rebuilt the lib directory and I was able to access bugzilla again from my browser again.

Comment: I've been looking for 2 weeks, and finally found this post!
Thank you!

I had Bugzilla 5.0.3 on Ubuntu 14.04 and upgraded to Ubuntu 16.04.  Of course, Apache failed because of Bugzilla.

I updated CPAN and modules, then renamed bugzilla/lib, and ran bugzilla/checksetup.pl.

Now, everything works!

Comment: @Terence glad I could help. I've gotten so much help from others, nice to contribute to others.